# Resetting required validation errors onChange Laravel + Vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I have a select box with 2 options. There are "child" options in both these options. So, if Option 1 is selected, one text field (Option1child) shows up and if Option 2 is selected 2 more checkbox  fields (group) (Option2child1, Option2child2) shows up.

All of these fields are required.

So with Option1 selected and if user submits without entering Option1child, Laravel sends a "required" error.

If Option2 is selected and no child options checked, it shows the required error here too.

I am doing this in Vue + Laravel.

The problem is, when I select Option1 and submit, it shows the error, and when I select Option2 again and submit, I get another set of errors + the old error in the form.errors array. What I want to do is reset the errors array when we change the Option and submit. I can do this in Vue with

form.errors = {};

But how can we reset this in Laravel which seems to be validating again.

Validation in Laravel is done something like this:

```
 attr = $request->validate([
        'sendto' => 'required',
        'to' => 'required_if:sendto,==,Option1',
        'groups' => 'required_if:sendto,==,Option2|required_without:batches|nullable',
        'batches' => 'required_if:sendto,==,Option2|required_without:groups|nullable'
 ]);
```

I hope I am clear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel validation will handle the data in request every time you send the request, I thought that happened in your vue component you should debug data sent to your Laravel controller and be sure the data be correct from your vue component side.

Comment: Ok, I have this code in vue. 
let submit = () => {
    form.post("/sendemails");
}

Its sending all the fields to laravel and I think that is the reason its sending back all the errors, is it possible to just check the childoptions for the one selected above? How do we do that? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it seems if we only put required_if, it seems to work as expected. but I need at least one of the Option2child selected. That was the reason I used required_without. Can we combine these 2 in a proper manner?

Comment: make things simple as you can, you can create an object in your vue containing data sent to the backend, and every time you submit your form empty this object and assign to it the new values, I hope this scenario is clear to you.

Comment: Thanks.. resetting is done by itself it seems.. because of the rules I had, it was causing me problems. I will post the fix I found below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems required_if and required_without cannot be used together. I found a fix by doing this so it no longer shows the old errors and I also get child options required error in both cases.

To recap, I have a select option with 2 options. If Option1 is selected, there is a child option which is required. If Option2 is selected there are 4 options of which at least 1 is required. The code that worked for me is:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'newsletter' => 'required',
        'sendto' => 'required',
        'to' => 'required_if:sendto,==,Option1',
        'groups' => 'sometimes',
    ]);

    $validator->sometimes(array('groups', 'batches', 'gender', 'countries'), 'required_if:sendto,==,Option2', function ($input) {
        return ($input->groups == [] && $input->batches == [] && $input->gender == []  && $input->countries == []);
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
```

I hope it helps someone. I have had hard time trying to find a fix on the internet.

If anyone has a better code, I will be happy to implement it.